# Error sending an array within a JSON object

Tags: json, go, iris-go

In order to send this JSON with Iris Go

```
{
  "response_type": "in_channel",
  "text": "It's 80 degrees right now.",
  "attachments": [
    {
        "text":"Partly cloudy today and tomorrow"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying with this but is not working

```
ctx.JSON(iris.Map{
    "text": "It's 80 degrees right now.",
    "response_type": "in_channel",
    "attachments":[{ "text": "Partly cloudy today and tomorrow" }],
})
```

Because the following error appear in the **attachments line**

```
syntax error: unexpected {, expecting expression
```

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: a little bit of context around iris: https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter/issues/160 and http://www.florinpatan.ro/2016/10/why-you-should-not-use-iris-for-your-go.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Go code, you don't specify a type for the array or its element. Assuming you want it to be `iris.Map`:

```
ctx.JSON(iris.Map{
    "text": "It's 80 degrees right now.",
    "response_type": "in_channel",
    "attachments": []iris.Map{iris.Map{ "text": "Partly cloudy today and tomorrow" }},
})
```

Comment: @SoldierCorp note that you can omit the 3rd `iris.Map` from the provided example to reduce stutter as is explained [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals). Mainly this part: *"Within a composite literal of array, slice, or map type T, elements or map keys that are themselves composite literals may elide the respective literal type if it is identical to the element or key type of T."*

Comment: @mkopriva Didn't know that, I will check that article. Thanks!